# how to use $project to retrieve targeted array according to selected id?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

data structure goes like this:

```
{
        "_id" : "10001",
        "comments" : [
                {
                        "comid" : "3",
                        "comtime" : "2014",
                        "author" : "jenny",
                        "replycomment" : [
                                {
                                        "comid" : "34",
                                        "comtime" : "2015",
                                        "author" : "jack"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

i want to query array in replycomment like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([{"$project":{"comments":{"replycomment":{"comtime":1}}}},{"$match":{"comments.comid":"3"}}])
```

but it doesn't work...

is something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your projection there is no more field "comments.comid" so you can't match on it.

Try to match before projection or add field "comments.comid" to your projection:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$match":{"comments.comid":"3"}},
    {"$project":{_id:0, "comments":{"replycomment": {"comtime":1}}}},
    {"$project":{"replycomment":"$comments.replycomment"}}
])

db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$project":{_id:0, "comments":{comid:1, "replycomment": {"comtime":1}}}},
    {"$match":{"comments.comid":"3"}},
    {"$project":{_id:0, "replycomment":"$comments.replycomment"}}
])
```

Comment: seems that after i run this ,i have result ,it contains _id,comments,and replycomment these fields. is it possible that only return the replycomment field instead of _id ,comments?   @Volodymyr Synytskyi

Comment: so these two methods are same ,either one is ok? @Volodymyr Synytskyi

Comment: @simonchou Yes, but I would recommend to use the first one. It should be a little faster.